# Is there a better way to resize an image that is in the form of a numpy array?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, image-preprocessing

I'm new to neural networks, and have been practicing image preprocessing.  I am trying to resize images that are in the form of numpy arrays, and this is my current method:

```
# using tensorflow, resize the image
im = tf.image.resize(img_as_array, [299, 299])

# then use .eval() which returns a numpy array in the size I want
im_arr = im.eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having to convert between `tf.tensor` and `np.ndarray` tensor data types, you can use `skimage` (scikit-image) to resize the image directly on `np.ndarray` objects using the following code segment:

```
import skimage.transform

kwargs = dict(output_shape=self._size, mode='edge', order=1, preserve_range=True)
im = skimage.transform.resize(im, **kwargs).astype(im.dtype)
```

To install `skimage`, follow the installation instructions here: https://pypi.org/project/scikit-image/.  Hope this helps!